# How can I create a dynamically-allocated 2D array out of any maze ASCII text file?

Tags: c++

I found a simple way to convert any ASCII file into a string regardless of its dimensions, but this doesn't help me a lot because I need it in a dynamically-allocated 2D array? Which attributes I want to convert later on to Graph attributes to solve the maze. What is the best way to get a dynamically-allocated 2D array out of my string or—if my approach is not the best one—out of the ASCII text file with the maze? I want to be able to convert white space in the 2d Array to vertices and connect them with edges where I will have a starting and ending vertex.

```
std::ifstream in("d:\\mazes\\mymaze.txt");
std::string s((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)),
std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
cout << s;
```

Comment: What kind of data do you have in your file? Just numbers?

Comment: Do you really need to have all lines in memory at once instead of processing it line by line or entry by entry? I'd create the graph object and than read the input one entry at a time (in a while-loop using `>>` operator with cautious use of `skip`/`skipws`) and add them to the graph.

Comment: Ok now after I have the Entire maze into array of Strings : "s" I wonder how to convert it to graph. Do I really need to convert it first to 2d Array or to adjacency matrix? I might need to create case switch looking for : #,p,t and default to be white space? any ideas.. i dont know if my questions are clear ... please ask me to clarify if you cant understand me

Comment: thanks that one is not working either way ... I will have to read it line by line ...

Comment: I can't reach the maze hypoerlink

Comment: I would have said your needs are clear, but I'm not sure that you are thinking about this the right way. *Of course* you are going to have to accept the input piecemeal and build up a data structure as you go. In old fashioned c I would use a ragged array, in c++ I would consider `std::vector< std::string >` or `std::vector< std::vector< char > >` (at least as a step along the way) despite the slightly awkward access semantics. Once you have the data you have the option of making a nicer container and discarding the awkward loading structure.

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work:

```
int rows = 4;//When you change these the array will change size
int cols = 4;

// declaration
int ** a;

// allocate
a = new int*[rows];
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    a[i] = new int[cols];

// set the values
for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        a[i][j] = 0;

// destruct
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    delete a[i];
delete a[];
```